# Pasar valores de data a una función dentro del evento .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

estoy creando 3 tablas en html, la una depende de la otra, coloque un checkbox donde se selecciona la boleta, quisiera al interior de la function del .click(), que reciba los valores de  data previos, para poder manejarlos, además tengo otra duda cuando realizo el .click, quisiera  cambiar al input de esta forma `$('input[type="checkbox" name="boleta"]')`, pero me sale un error, capaz que no sea la síntaxis correcta.

```
function mostrarBoleta(data){
    //console.log(data);
    if (data == "No existe cliente."){
        hide_table()
        $("#error_msg").html("<br><br>"+data);
    }
    else{
        $("#error_msg").html("");
        $( "#myData" ).show();
        //primera tabla Datos Cliente
        var rut_p = $("#rut_p");
        var nombre_cliente = $("#nombre_cliente");
        var direccion = $("#direccion");
        rut_p.html(data.rut);
        nombre_cliente.html(data.nombre_cl);
        direccion.html(data.direccion);
        //Segunda tabla Boletas
        var content = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < data.boletas.length; i++){
            content += "<tr><td><input id=\""+i+"\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"boleta\" >"+"</td>";
            content += "<td>" + data.boletas[i].num_boleta + "</td>";
            //Probablemente se puede optimizar
            var fecha_obtenida = new Date(data.boletas[i].created_at);
            var dia = fecha_obtenida.getDate();
            var mes = fecha_obtenida.getMonth()+1;
            var annio = fecha_obtenida.getFullYear();
            //--------------------------------------------------
            content += "<td>" + dia+"/"+mes+"/"+annio + "</td>";
            content += "<td>" + data.boletas[i].total + "</td>";
            content += "</tr>";
        }
        $( "#table_checkbox").find( "tbody" ).html(content);
        /*selección de boleta para rellenar la tercera tabla una vez que haya sido elegida*/
        $('input[type="checkbox"][name="boleta"]').click(
            function(){
                if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                    var id;
                    id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
                    //creo que deberia rellenarla aca
                    console.log(id);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

//Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no puedes hacer esto

```
$('input[type="checkbox" name="boleta"]')
```

debería de ser más o menos así:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='boleta']")
```

Por otro lado, para hacer lo que quieres del click, podrías hacer la llamada a la otra función pasandole como parámetro lo que necesitas:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='boleta']").on("click", function(element){
    //hacer lo que tengas que hacer
    llamadaAtuFuncion(element)
});
```

*update*

para obtener el id del checkbox cuando se ha hecho click, puede hacer algo como esto

```
var tuCheckBox= '';
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='boleta']").each(function (index) {  
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
          tuCheckBox = $(this).val();
       }
    });
```

*De esta manera estarías obteniendo el valor del check seleccionado, si quisieras obtener el id del checkbox seleccionado, sería así*

```
    var tuCheckBox= '';
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='boleta']").each(function (index) {  
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
          tuCheckBox = this.attr("id");
       }
    });
```

de esa manera le estarías enviando los datos del check seleccionado, también podrías usar `$(this).val()` o cualquier otra cosa.

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.

Un saludo

Comment: disculpa, realize una edición, la función principal se llama mostrarboleta(data){} y quisiera que la data de la principal entrara en la funcion del click, eso es lo que no se hacer, arregle esto $("input[type='checkbox'][name='boleta']") y funciono

Comment: @Empower lo dicho, harías lo que te he dije en mi respuesta. en el on(click), harías la llamada a tu función enviandole como parámetro element que se declara en la función anónima de click

Comment: no, cuando el usuario realiza el click en el checkbox, necesito obtener el id de ese checkbox, pero no me sirve lanzarlo a mostrarboleta(data), porque en esa funcion es donde esta el evento click del checkbox, está alli mismo y no se, porque soy novato como volver ese checkbox de allí iterable, porque claramente debo esperar que el usuario presione el checkbox, para luego poder utilizar ese id de checkbox en la misma funcion de mostrarboleta(data)

Comment: talvés sugieres otra forma de extraer el id de ese checkbox al ser clickeado por el usuario?, muchas gracias

Comment: @Empower si necesitas obtener el id del ese checkbox lo unico que tienes que hacer es obtener el atributo id del checkbox cuando se ha hecho click. Edito mi pregunta para que puedas ver como hacerlo.

Comment: Me has sido de mucha ayuda, solo que tengo otra duda, te la explicare, ahora que tengo la id del checkbox necesito hacer un loop con esa id en númerico: for(let k = 0; k < data.boletas[tuCheckBox].productos.length; k++){}

Comment: @Empower no entiendo bien a que te refieres con eso que dices de hacer "un loop en numerico"

Comment: porque quiero rellenar otra tabla con la boleta que fue seleccionada mediante este checkboox, que cargue los productos, ya que el checkbox me dice la posicion, mediante su id a que boleta debe acceder, para luego empezar el loop en productos

Comment: @Empower pues ya lo que tendrías que hacer es dentro de ese for que me comentas es hacer una tabla html o añadir tantos <td> como neceites como compartes en tu código, eso está bien, a mi parecer

Comment: si, funciona como lo hacía, solo que solo deseo que se llene esa tabla cuando el usuario haga click, por eso a la function interior del click debería pasarle los datos de arriba, pero cuando intento no me deja

Comment: @Empower pues dentro de la función del click, puedes capturar tu tabla por id o por clase y crearle un each, como te mostré anteriormente e ir creando tanto td como necesites